# How do I force the regression line to go through (0,1)?

Tags: sas

Edited question: now the restriction of the intercept needs to be materialized through a REG statement within a PROC SGPANEL.

```
The syntax is:

PROC SGPANEL DATA=...;
 PANELBY ...;
 REG Y=... X=... / ...;
RUN;
```

I don't think that the RESTRICT statement works here. So what can I do in this situation?

...

Previous question (answered in a satisfactory manner):

I would like to force my regression line - using PROC SGPANEL - to go through (0,1) (not (0,0), then I would use the NOINT option in the MODEL statement). How can I do this?

I've created a dummy variable in place of my response variable y:

dummy_y=y-1

Now my idea is to use the NOINT option *and* somehow replace the values on the vertical axis which are (-1, 0, 1, 2) with the values (0, 1, 2, 3).

Now my questions are:

1) How can I manipulate the values on the vertical axis according the intention described above?

2) How can I otherwise force the intercept to be one?

My syntax is as follows:

proc reg date=DS;

model dummy_y=x / noint;

run;

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can modify the data before running `proc reg`.  The idea of a dummy variable seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. However, I am not sure that I understand. I did create the dummy variable by subtracting 1 from my response before running PROC REG. So the point (0,0) is "actually" (0,1). Now I want the value "0" on the vertical axis to be replaced by "1", "1" to be replaced by "2" and so forth..

Comment: @Fuente The coefficients _a_ and _b_ of regression line _y = ax + b_ are estimated using the least squares method. `NOINT` option means that  you want to omit _b_ and fit a linear model in the form of _y = ax_

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try your second option: using an intercept but with the constraint that it should be 1 with the restrict statement:

```
proc reg date=DS;

model y=x ;
restrict intercept=1;

run;
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution:  https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect020.htm.

Comment: I did not know the RESTRICT statement. It seems useful. However shouldn't I just use my original response variable y, and then force the intercept to be 1 using RESTRICT? That is the dummy is not needed after all?

Comment: Indeed, that is what I wanted to show. I have updated my answer.